# Prove that this expression is always an integer

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integers

Prove that $$\frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^{n+1}}$$

is always an integer

From the counting problem permutation ways of $n$ times number from $1$ to $n$.

We can notice that $$\frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}$$

is always an integer

Do they have a relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint : Consider partitioning $n^2$ objects into $n$ blocks each of size $n$.

Comment: I see some terms canceled out but it will $(n!)^n$ also? Since from $n^2$ to $n$ there is $n$ term.

Comment: That's right ... the order of the elements in each $n-$set can be arranged in $n!$ ways.(giving a factor of $(n!)^n$) and then these sets could be ordered in $n!$ ways ... giving another factor of $n!$

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean. if we think the order of blocks doesn't matter, then we need to divide $n!$ since for each combination of blocks we have $n!$ way. Is it right?

Comment: Yeah! ... that's right.